# Do i have to use bump mapping for this...?

Tags: light

I'm creating a dragons head, and i just finished the tongue.
Now i want to give the tongue more "texture"...

For example, when i choose smooth lighting, it just looks smooth (obviously)
But can i somehow make the light look a bit more "dotted" like it would on a real tongue...?
Or must i create a bump map to get that effect?
I'm not trying to make it look super advanced, just not so smooth.

English is not my native language, so i don't know what this is actually called ;-;

Answer (score 5):

Beside the usual diffuse, specular, and all the other textures - you can apply some depth to your object via the following:

[1. Bump Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping)
Bump mapping adjusts the normals on a surface to make it appear that there are bumps, when there really aren't. Bump maps are grayscale. Bump mapping a Normal mapping both benefit from being able to create this illusion without needing additional geometry. A single plane can look very textured, even with just one polygon.

[2. Normal Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mapping)
Normal mapping does the same thing as bump mapping, but with more precision and control. Normal maps use the red, green, and blue channels to encode x, y and z deflection angles for surface normals. They typically look bluish.

[3. Displacement Mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping)
Displacement mapping changes the position of vertices, based on an image texture. This has the advantage of providing real bumps, but requires more geometry. Displacement maps can be encoded either as grayscale like bump maps, or in color channels like normal maps. Many softwares allow bump maps and normal maps to be interpreted by displacement algorithms, for convenience.

It depends on the look you want to achieve which combination is best.
Hope this helps you a little bit.

Here, the left ball is using a bump map, the right one a displacement map.

[image: The left ball is using a bump map, the right one a displacement map.]

Comment: I guess i need a bump map then. But is there really no way to change how the light reflects off the object? That's seems weird to me... but i just started using blender yesterday xD

Comment: Bump mapping is the way to adjust the way the light reflects on your object. The alternative is using insane amounts of geometry to actually make the surface of your object bumpy. You can use a noise texture to stop your surface being smooth.

Comment: You should also experiment with a specular map. Often a spec map provides the "texture" that your eye is wanting to see. You can do this in Cycles by plugging a Noise node into the color slot of a glossy node. Or you can do this in BI with a regular texture, but just turn on "Intensity" or "Color" in the "Specular" section of the "Influence" panel.